# Mosquitto TLS connection and SNI

Tags: mosquitto, sim800

I am using sim800c module as client to server mosquitto  with ssl  (tls 1.2) conection.
sim800c when sending ssl handshake , does not send  extensions parameter (SNI) in Transport Layer Security and mosquitto disconnects connection after handshake packet (Client Hello).
I tested the connection with client  software like Mqtt.Fx that supported SNI And the connection  established .
is there a way that Mosquitto  to ignore SNI ??

best regard.

is there a way that Mosquitto  to ignore SNI ??

Comment: Just to help, what version of mosquitto are you using?

Comment: Also include your `mosquitto.conf` file and are you providing a hostname to the sim800c or just an IP address (and does it match the CN/SAN in the broker cert)?

Comment: @hardillb . mosquitto version 2.0.17 - I tested with both hostname and IP and no difference was observed .

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76982556/edit) the question to add details. Include both `mosquitto.conf` and a log snippet of a connection attempt

Comment: `tls_version` needs to be applied to both `listener` blocks and since mosquitto doesn't support virtual hosts it is very unlikely that it makes use of the SNI extension at all.

Comment: Remove the `ca_file` as that only applies to verifying client certs and change `cert_file` to use the `fullchain.pem`